# Embedding Paper.js script in Jquery Mobile Page

Tags: jquery-mobile, paperjs

I have a puzzle game similar to this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/395453/Html5-Jigsaw-Puzzle

which I have embedded in a jquery mobile page.

The puzzle displays, but I can't interact with it on my phone. Touching the screen results in scrolling instead of interaction with the puzzle.

If I go to the page as a non-JQM page it works fine on the phone.

How can I have it embedded in a JQM page and still allow interaction with the puzzle?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at this answer: [How to disable scrolling temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily)

It's not paperjs specific, but it seems like it's exactly what you are after.

I've recently created a screencast on paperjs at http://tagtree.tv/canvas-with-paper-js, go check it out if you've got some time.